# How do I Integrate TestRail with my Pytest test cases?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, python-unittest, testrail, pytest-html

I have my automation test cases written in pytest. The Automation Scripts are in my Local and in Git as well. I just signed up for TestRail & I'm not sure about how to map my pytest test cases with TestRail testcases.

I'm expecting the Reports to be Generated in TestRail whenever my I run pytest Automation Scripts.

Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/allankp/pytest-testrail
Try using this integration, it creates a testrun and adds results after all tests are finished, well documented and easy to use